# jQuery UI Multiselect - Select an option more than once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to ask if its possible to select an option in a jQuery UI Multiselect more than once.

To make it clear, assuming that i have a drop down with apples and oranges, is it possible to select 10 x Apples and 5 x Oranges?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is that going to help? Optgroup does nothing to count selections.

Comment: Is there any other plugin that can do this?